# Bug in the Late Answers, First Posts and Suggested Edits review queues allow to arbitrarily mark items as reviewed, even if they were not

Tags: bug, review

Both in the Late Answers and First Posts queue, clicking "edit", **not** editing the post and clicking "Save Edits" triggers the dimming of the "No Action Needed" button and the appearence of the "I'm Done" button:

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

[image: screenshot3]

Aside from the "per se" harmless GUI bug, the problem is that this allows to click the "I'm Done" button, which has the effect of marking the item as reviewed, even if it was not: [link to the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/140717/380067), [link to the review](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/469539).

As you can see, despite the fact that the post hasn't been touched (the edit doesn't appear in the [revisions history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/140717/revisions)), the item in the review has still been marked as reviewed.

A similiar thing happens also in the Suggested Edits queue, although I was able to do this only once; I don't have screenshots for this one but I have the links; clicking "Improve Edit", **not** editing the post and clicking "Save Edits" has the effect of marking the item as reviewed (as approved and edited), even if it was not: [link to the question](https://askubuntu.com/q/681923/380067), [link to the review](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/475603).

As you can see, despite the fact that the post hasn't been touched (the edit doesn't appear in the [revisions history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/681923/revisions)), the item in the review has still been marked as reviewed.

Comment: No worry @Pat, happens to the best. ;)